# Google maps embed API fallback coordinates

Tags: google-maps

I have a website that contains a database of places, mostly stores and small businesses, and i want to add a google map for every business on the site. I have a name and coordinates for each business, but not all of them are listed on google maps. If i make a Google Maps Embed API map like this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=APIKEY&q=Place name
```

I will get a marker on that place, but if that place is not found, is it possible to make it put a marker on the coordinates provided?

I know i can just use the coordinates without any name, but in case the place is listed on google maps, querying its name instead of coordinates will display details about the place

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can still place a marker as long as you have the lat and long.

You can add your business to Google Map over [here](http://www.google.com/business/?gmbsrc=us-en-ha-se-z-gmb-s-z-h~bk&ppsrc=GMBS0).